# Why does my objective function in my LP file, generated with Ilog Cplex, contains variables with coefficient equal to 0 ?

Tags: cplex

I am using Ilog Cplex to solve my problem. I also use it to print out an LP file of my problem in order to solve it again with different parameters later on.

When solving, I want to print out the value of each variable in the objective function. The problem is, the objective function contains variables with a coefficient equal to 0. Therefore, not all the variables in the objective function are relevant to me.

I would like to know :

1. Why does Cplex add variables with a null coefficient in the objective function ?
2. Can I remove them somehow ?

If I find a way to print the value of a variable from a partial name, that would also answer my question, since I know part of the name of all relevant variables. For example, I would like to print the value of all variables that contains 'global' in their name. Although, I don't think I can do that with Cplex Interactive Optimizer.

Comment: How are you building your model in the first place?  Which API are you using?  What commands are you using in the interactive?  What does your LP file actually look like (can you provide a small example)?

Comment: Turning the question around - are you adding terms in the objective with a zero coefficient? I'd check what your code that builds the model is doing, specifically what gets added to the objective. I have never seen CPLEX itself adding terms to the objective.

Comment: The tineractive optimizer supports a limited amount of regular expressions for printing solutions. Try `disp sol var *global*`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why CPLEX includes all variables in the objective when writing to LP format (even those with a coefficient of zero). One reason is that, when reading in an LP file, some types of constraints require that a variable "exists" before it can be used (note that this is a legacy implementation detail, not necessarily a hard requirement).

For example, consider the following toy LP:

```
Minimize                                                                        
obj: x1 + x2                                                                    
Subject to                                                                      
c1: x1 + x2 <= 10                                                               
SOS                                                                             
s1: s1:: x1:1 x2:2 x3:3                                                         
End
```

If we try to read this with the interactive, we'll get:

```
CPLEX> Warning, line 6: Name 'x3' does not exist.
CPLEX Error  1616: Line 6: Expected identifier, found ':'.
No file read.
```

If we instead include `x3` in the objective, like so:

```
Minimize                                                                        
obj: x1 + x2 + 0 x3                                                             
Subject to                                                                      
c1: x1 + x2 <= 10                                                               
SOS                                                                             
s1: s1:: x1:1 x2:2 x3:3                                                         
End
```

Then, CPLEX will happily accept the problem.

Another possibly more compelling reason why CPLEX does this, is that sometimes when a program builds a model, there are temporary or dummy variables that are created. These may or may not be important to the actual model. In order to write something to the LP file that is as close as possible as what the program built in memory, there are times when useless or innocuous things are written to the LP file. For example, if a variable is created, but never used, it at least shows up in the LP file as a variable with a zero coefficient in the objective file. This may make it possible to reproduce some behavior that the user observes in tech support situations.

There are many quirks to the LP format. You can read about them [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/FileFormats/topics/LP.html).

Comment: "if a variable is created, but never used, it at least shows up in the LP file as a variable with a zero coefficient in the objective file". This is actually a good indication that probably something is wrong in the code if it is not intended for such variables to appear in the objective function.